# SQL query to update one for one

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I have table A with one to many relationship to table B. Whenever I do an update I create new record in table A with a new batch of records related created in table B. I had a bug in my code so when new items where being created the order of them was being reversed. I need to write a SQL query to update items in table B related to second item in table A to be the same as the ones related to first item in table A. I hope it makes any sense, will try to illustrate:

A1 -> B - 1234
A2 -> B - 4321

I want to update second set of values from table B to be the same as the ones related to A1 (1234)

Comment: Hi, can you post up your codes? So that we can check which part of your code is creating the problem

Comment: you want to update all records in B to have A as master instead of B ? or what is it that you want ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not think of records order in database table. The only way to specify order of rows is `ORDER BY` clause in `SELECT` statement.

Make `row_order` or `idx` column in table `B` and put there required value for each item.

In some cases you will also get different order of `B` items for the first/source `A` record when selecting them without specifying order in `ORDER BY` clause.

Relational database table has no notion about neither *row order* nor *column order*.